# Nextcloud users' settings "Group admin for" - what is it?

Tags: user-groups, configure, nextcloud

I've just finished configuring a Nextcloud server running on Apache2. It's the latest version. This is the first time I set up such a server.

While I was fiddling with the settings I created a non-admin account (two accounts including me) and I put myself and this account in an additional group, called "*Database*", with the intention to give the users who are in this group acess to a database file. Among the settings for users (columns), it lets me set a value I found rather confusing: "*Group admin for*". It lets me select only the *Database* group for this entry. I tried to set it for me and I didn't see any difference. What does this thing do? What does actually happen if I set it for a user?

Comment: ""What does this thing do?"  If you assigned a user to be a group administrator, that user would be able to add/remove users, into that particular user group.  [It also seems a group administrator has the ability to delete other users also.](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/3630).   As for the reason, it only allows you to select a single group, you only have a single user group currently.

Comment: @Ramhound so, does it mean that a group admin can put in and remove people from a specific group or array of groups while not being able to delete the accounts from Nextcloud?

Comment: Based on the open bug report provided, it appears if you make them a group administrator of a group, they can actually delete the user altogether

Comment: @Ramhound it does not look very useful then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion of what a "Group Admin" is.  The system designers are using the term incorrectly.  They should have termed it "Admin Group".  English is confusing.  But for "Group Admin", admin is the noun and group is the adjective what type of administrator it is.  So in essence, "Group Admin" should mean "Administator of a Group".  But they have incorrectly define it like "group of administrators".  Hence, "Admin Group" where group is the noun and admin is the adjective describing what type of group it is.

The developers are refusing to address the issues and are ignoring the community which is a very bad sign for a project.

I suggested today (and this issue has been onging for 4-5 years now) that they create a "managed by" tag for User Groups where a list of managers can control the membership of the group itself (not of the users in the group).

https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/20399

I think the Devs realize this is a huge issue and blocker for many organizations.  They just have to figure out how to not isolate existing users who like it how it is.  I think the "managed by" solution gives the best of both worlds.

Comment: This. A "group admin" should manage the users' membership to a group, not the users themselves. The current setup only makes sense if the only reason a user has an account on the Nextcloud instance is to be part of that one single group, maybe to work on a single project. For all other usecases, this functionality is useless and dangerously misleading.